# what's the reason for the unexpect behavior of plot()

Tags: python, sage

```
def f(u):
    value = 0.0
    if u > -1 and u < 1:
        value = u * u
    return value
```

Given the above, the following produces the expected plot:

```
plot(f,(x,-5,5))
```

But `plot(f(x),(x,-5,5))` just draws a horizontal line.  Can anyone explain what's going on?

Answer (score 1):

The former passes the function, allowing it to be called inside `plot()`. The latter calls the function once and passes the returned value, resulting in the same value each time.

Comment: if so, then why does `plot(sin,(x,-5,5))` produce the same correct plot as `plot(sin(x),(x,-5,5))`?

Comment: Where are you getting `sin` from?

Comment: Nowhere.  It's there by default without me having to import anything.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to what @Ignacio said, the cause is the function being called once. The problem with this vs other functions like `sin` is the conditional. The `if` statement is evaluated when the function is called and not preserved as a symbolic statement. That is, the `u > -1 and u < 1`<sup>[1]</sup> is evaluated on the first function call and `result` is treated accordingly (i.e. left at `0`).

As an illustration of what is happening:

```
sage: x = var('x')
sage: print ":)" if x > 0 else ":("
:(
```

There is no way to get around this in general<sup>[2]</sup>, because Python has to evaluate the condition in the `if` statement to work out which code path to take when the function is called.

#### Best case solution

There is a solution that should work (but doesn't yet). Sage provides [`Piecewise`](http://www.sagemath.org/doc/reference/sage/functions/piecewise.html), so you can define `f` as:

```
f = Piecewise([((-5, -1), ConstantFunction(0)), 
               ((-1, 1),     x*x), 
               ((1, 5),   ConstantFunction(0))],
              x)
```

Unfortunately, the implementation of `Piecewise` is as yet incomplete, and severely lacking, so the only way to plot this seems to be:

```
f.plot()
```

(Limitations: trying to call `f` with a variable causes errors; it doesn't work with the conventional `plot`; you can't restrict the domain in `Piecewise.plot`, it plots the whole thing (hence why I restricted it to ±5); it doesn't cope with infinite intervals.)

#### Working solution

You could also just detect whether the argument to `f` is a number or variable and do the appropriate action based on that:

```
def f(u):
    try:
        float(u) # see it's a number by trying to convert
        return u*u if -1 < u < 1 else 0.0
    except TypeError: # the conversion failed
        if callable(f):
            return lambda uu: f(u(uu))
        else:
            return f
```

Note the `callable` call, it checks to see if `u` is a function (in some sense), if so returns the composition of `f` with `u`.

This version allows us to do things like:

```
sage: f(10)
0.0
sage: f(x)(0.5)
0.25
sage: f(x+3)(-2.2)
0.64
```

and it also works perfectly fine with `plot`, in either form. (Although it warns about `DeprecationWarnings` because of the `u(uu)` syntax; there are ways to get around this using `u.variables` but they are fairly awkward.)

**Note**: This "working" solution is quite fragile, and very suboptimal; the `Piecewise` version would be the correct solution, if it worked.

[1]: Python actually allows you to write this as `-1 < u < 1`. Pretty cool.

[2]: Although in some special cases you can, e.g. if you know `x > 0`, then you can use `assume(x > 0)` which means the example will print `:)`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a (possibly) simpler solution for now, using lambdas.

```
sage: plot(lambda x:f(x), (x,-5,5))
```

[image: plot of your function]